# BFS method that returns the shortest way between two words (printing the words)

Tags: methods, path, breadth-first-search

Maybe you have seen my other threads, been struggling with this a bit, here is my code currently:

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista=[]

    def put(self,x):
        self.lista.append(x)

    def get(self):
        if not len(self.lista)==0:
            return self.lista.pop(0)

    def isempty(self):
        if len(self.lista)==0:
            return True
        else:
            False

    def length(self):
        return len(self.lista)


    def dequeue(self):
        if not len(self.lista)==0:
            n=self.lista.pop(0)
            return n

    def enqueue(self,item):
        self.lista.insert(0,item)

class Word:
    def __init__(self,w,f=None):
        self.word=w
        sel.parent=f

def hamta():
    ordlista=[]
    fil=open("labb9text.txt")
    ordlista=[]
    for line in fil.readlines():
        ordlista.append(line.strip())
    return ordlista

def setlista():
    ordlista=hamta()
    setlista=set()
    for a in ordlista:
        if a not in setlista:
            setlista.add(a)
    return setlista

def hittabarn(parent):
    mangd=setlista() 
    children=[]
    lparent=list(parent)
    mangd.remove(parent)
    for word in mangd:
        letters=list(word)
        count=0
        i=0
        for a in letters:
            if a==lparent[i]:
                count+=1
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
            if count==2:
                if word not in children:
                    children.append(word)
            if i>2:
                break
    return children

def way(start,slut): 
    queue=Queue()
    queue.enqueue(start)
    visited=set()                       
    while not queue.isempty():
        vertex=queue.get()
        if vertex==slut:
            return True
        else:
            s=hittabarn(start)
            for vertex in s:
                if vertex not in visited:
                    queue.put(vertex)
                else:
                    visited.add(vertex)
        return False
```

My way method is working and it's returning what it's supposed to return, which is True if there is a way, and false if there isn't a way. My new problem is that I somehow have to create a new class (I would much rather do this with a list in my way-method but that's not the assignment) called Word. I'm supposed to give the items I insert the queue Word-attributes and with this I'm supposed to print the "path", lets say, for example, I have "dum" and "vis", then it might look like this: dum –> dus –> dis –> vis

I have always been bad with node-attributes, does anyone have a clue of what I can do?

Comment: You are right Kyll, will do that!

Comment: Anyone got any idea of how I implement this, any help at this point is warmly welcome!